# Period of periodic solution to forced nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have the following possibly nonlinear ODE:

$\dot{x} = f(x) + \cos\omega t$

Suppose that the equation has a periodic solution, i.e., $\exists$ T > 0 such that $x(t) = x(t+T)$. 
Is it true that $T = k\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? If so, how would you show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the ODE
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= f(x) + \cos{\omega t} \\
x  &= \int f(x)dt + \int \cos{\omega t}\ dt \\
x(t)  &= \int f(x(t)) \ dt + \frac{\sin {\omega t}}{\omega} + C \\
x(t+T) &= \int f(x(t+T)) \ d(t+T) + \frac{\sin {\omega (t+T)}}{\omega} + C \\
&= \int f(x(t+T)) \ dt + \frac{\sin {\omega (t+T)}}{\omega} + C \\
  \text{if} \ T = \frac{2 \pi k}{\omega} \\
x(t+T) &= \int f(x(t+T)) \ dt + \frac{\sin {\omega t}}{\omega} + C \\
\because x(t+T) = x(t) \\
x(t+T) &= \int f(x(t)) \ dt + \frac{\sin {\omega t}}{\omega} + C
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, $x(t)$ is periodic with period $T =\frac{2 \pi k}{\omega}$

Answer (score 0):

$x$ and thus $\dot x$ are $T$-periodic. Thus $$\dot x(t)-f(x(t))$$ has $T$ as one of its period. If there is a smaller positive minimal period, it has the form $T/k$ for some integer $k$. On the other side is a function with frequency $ω$. Equality is only possible if $T/k=2\pi/ω$, or as claimed
$$
T=\frac{2k\pi}{ω}.
$$